# Why is cron ignoring a / (forward slash) interval?

Tags: debian, cron

I want to set up a job to run every 15 minutes, starting at the 5th minute.

This is my crontab line:

```
5/15 * * * * /root/job.sh >> /root/job.log
```

But it only runs once an hour, on the fifth minute. I confirmed by checking /var/log/syslog.

On Debian 7.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Have you looked at this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19204734)

I think what you are looking for is:

```
5-59/15 * * * * /root/job.sh >> /root/job.log
```

Comment: I like your Stackoverflow link

Comment: Thanks, that's a great link. I'd looked for a similar scenario but I guess I didn't think of the right keywords in order to find that discussion.

Obviously the part I missed is that I actually needed to specify a range for the stepping to work. Thank you.

Comment: Another great link: [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#1/5_*_*_*_*). Shame on me, I didn't notice the `Non standard! May not work with every cron`  warning, and only this question explained it.

Answer (score 2):

What you've written in your `crontab` entry doesn't match your stated need. The manpage (`man 5 crontab`) is reasonably clear on this:

> Step  values can be used in conjunction with ranges. Following a range with "/" specifies skips of the number's value through the range. For example, "0-23/2" can be used in the hours field to specify command execution every other hour [...]

To run every 15 minutes starting at 5 minutes past the hour, I'd go for the simple `5,20,35,50`. A step value such as `5-59/15` should also work, but in this instance I'd suggest that its intent is *less* obvious.

Comment: Thanks for replying -- I had ended up with a simple list but was hoping for a more elegant solution. BTW, after realizing that a range is required for the step to work, it looks to me like 5/3 wouldn't work either.